# Copy file from URL to Azure BLOB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a file at a remote url such as http://www.site.com/docs/doc1.xls and i would like to copy that file onto my BLOB storage account.

I am aware and know of uploading files to a BLOB storage but wasn't sure how this can be done for a file from remote URL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try looking at [CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyFromBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717428.aspx) that takes a URI if you are using the .NET client library.

```
string accountName = "accountname";
string accountKey = "key";
string newFileName = "newfile2.png";
string destinationContainer = "destinationcontainer";
string sourceUrl = "http://www.site.com/docs/doc1.xls";

CloudStorageAccount csa = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = csa.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
var newBlockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(newFileName);
newBlockBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(sourceUrl), null, null, null);
```

Gaurav posted about this when it first came out.  Handy, and [his post](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/14/how-to-copy-an-object-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/) shows how to watch for completion since the operation is Async.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Quick note: The StartCopyFromBlob method of the Blob has now been deprecated in favor of StartCopy.