# Saving uploaded file from user with bot framework c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, botframework

I am currently trying to allow a user to upload a file to the bot during a dialog flow. From there the bot will take the file and upload it to blob storage. When the file comes in the content property is null, however the content url, name, and type all have the correct values.

```
    public virtual async Task StackTraceGathered(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        FileName = message.Attachments[0].Name;
        HttpPostedFileBase file = (HttpPostedFileBase)message.Attachments[0].Content;

        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(filePath);

        if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
        {
            var attachment = message.Attachments.First();
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Skype & MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
                if ((message.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || message.ChannelId.Equals("msteams", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    && new Uri(attachment.ContentUrl).Host.EndsWith("skype.com"))
                {
                    var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials().GetTokenAsync();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                }

                var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);

                var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

                await context.PostAsync($"Attachment of {attachment.ContentType} type and size of {contentLenghtBytes} bytes received.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Hi there! I'm a bot created to show you how I can receive message attachments, but no attachment was sent to me. Please, try again sending a new message including an attachment.");
        }
        PromptDialog.Text(context, ProblemStartDuration, "How long has this been an issue? (Provide answer in days, if issue has been occurring for less than one day put 1).");

        context.Wait(this.StackTraceGathered);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the issue, but I guess you are expecting the Content property to have something. It won't but you just need the Url. Two alternatives:

- Download the attachment in the bot (as the code you are using in the question) and upload to blob storage
- Try to upload the attachment directly from the Url using something like StartCopyFromBlob (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413627/copy-file-from-url-to-azure-blob))

Comment: I tried to upload the attachment directly while following the directions from the other stack overflow. It says the remote server returned a 404 not found error.

Comment: What happens if you navigate to the URL in the browser?

Comment: The content URL will either allow you to download the file or if it is an image it displays the image.

Comment: Yep I expected that.. so not sure why you got a 404... anyways, you can go with option #1

Comment: Could you explain a bit on how we would just upload to blob storage? I'm a bit confused on how to do that with the url. The example I was referencing using a file stream reader but that does not take in a uri.

Comment: I haven't tried; try to do some research on how that could be done with blob storage. However, the other option is still valid, download the stream and use that to upload the values